# Crear expresión regular

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo la siguiente de duda, ¿cómo puedo crear una expresión regular que coincida con los siguientes caracteres?

> '=&"<>~`.

Estoy intentando con:

```js
console.log( /^'=&"<>~`$/g.test('hola$buenas=tardes'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te hace falta encapsular tus simbolos en corchetes para que coincida cualquiera de esos caracteres y no usar el  `^` que indica explicitamente el inicio del string ni `$` que indica el final del string, puedes probar con ésto:

```
console.log(/['=&"<>~`.]+/g.test('hola$buenas=tardes'))
```

te recomiendo esta herramienta para probar tus expresiones https://regex101.com/

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.